# How to apply Bootstrap style to RichTextUploadingField?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, ckeditor

I attached CKeditor to my site.
When I load a high-resolution image, all Bootstrap responsiveness breaks.
This can be corrected - you need to manually assign the style and CSS class to the picture.
It’s inconvenient to do this manually every time, and the styles for other elements will also have to be written manually, and this takes a long time.

How can I apply Bootstrap style to all elements of this field? Maybe there is some kind of Bootstrap settings preset that needs to be written somewhere in settings.py?

I tried to manually set the image style in the ckeditor editor.

I want the Bootstrap style to be automatically applied to all elements (such as

, , , etc.)